# How to add loader for image on page load

Tags: jquery

How to add loader for image on page load .. I want to add loader until the main image is ready on page load.

how to do this

Thanks

**Update:**

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <nav class="social">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Showing a display Loading Icon Until the Page Loads Completely..</p>
            <img id="new" class="main-img" src="http://magento/pub/media/images/sizechart/babydoll.png"/></div>

    </nav>
</div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){alert("sdfsdf");

            // show loading image
             $('body').trigger('processStart');

            // main image loaded
            $('.main-img').on('load', function(){
                // hide the loading image
                $('body').trigger('processStop');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: where you have the loader image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below **jquery** code :

```
// show loading image
$('.loader_image_class').show();

// main image loaded
$('.main_image_class').on('load', function(){
  // hide the loading image
  $('.loader_image_class').hide();
});
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: Getting any error in console?

Comment: No ... ........

Comment: Can you share your code and where you adding this code?